# Execute different code present in header depending on whether it is C or C++

Tags: c++, c

I have made a header file with the following code :

```
#if C    //this code will execute if header file is included in .c file 
struct something{
};
#endif
#if CPP  //this code will be executed if header file is included in .cpp file
class something {
}
#endif
```

This header file can be included by both .c and .cpp file. What should I do to execute the respective code snippet?

Comment: This makes me feel uneasy. You can get brittle code by defining things like this.

Comment: Why do you need this? `struct something { };` works fine in C++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what the `__cplusplus` macro is for.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
// C++ code
#else
// C code
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need conditional compilation:

```
  typedef struct something {
  } something ;
```

will compile in both C and C++.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I have to declare structure for C and class for C++

Comment: @ChandanMahto In C++, structs are classes.

Comment: @melpomene I also have some member functions to deal with data so I decided to go with class.

Comment: @Chandan I think you need to pick one of C or C++ and program in that - trying to support both using conditional compilation rapidly becomes a nightmare.

Comment: @ChandanMahto `struct something { void member_function() { ... } };` is perfectly valid C++. Again, the `struct` keyword declares classes in C++.

Comment: @melpomene I got your point now. I thought that C++ doesn't support functions inside structure which was completely wrong.

Comment: Be aware that some compilers will encode classes and structures differently, so what you are doing is undefined behavior.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher In what way?

Comment: The mangling name for a struct and a class are different with visual studio, I'm not sure about any reassurance about how instances are layed out.